# Need to form an xpath locator at runtime based on the number of rows existing in a table

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

Below is my sample code.

```
:FOR    ${Temp}    IN    @{Status_Count_Elements}
\    Click Element    ${Temp}
\    ${Locator}=    Form Locator         ${Id_Locator}     ${index}
\    ${Data}=       Get Text             xpath=//*[@id="${Locator}"]
\    ${index} =     Evaluate             ${index} + 1
Close Browser
```

Output:

```
20180727 11:14:25.943 : INFO : ${Return} = toggle0
20180727 11:14:25.943 : INFO : ${Locator} = toggle0
20180727 11:14:25.977 : INFO : ${Data} = ***** not able to read text
20180727 11:14:25.978 : INFO : ${index} = 1
```

However i have tried to hard code the xpath and it works but it is wrong as it always reads the first row data.

```
:FOR    ${Temp}    IN    @{Status_Count_Elements}
\    Click Element    ${Temp}
\    ${Locator}=    Form Locator         ${Id_Locator}     ${index}
\    ${Data}=       Get Text             xpath=//*[@id="toggle0"]
\    ${index} =     Evaluate             ${index} + 1
Close Browser
```

Please let know how can i make it work dynamically.

Comment: Something like `xpath=//*[@id="toggle"+${index}]` this ?

Comment: Do you know how to enclose a string variable into Double quotes? I Guess that would help me.

Comment: I gave your suggestion a try. It failed[FAIL : Element with locator 'xpath=//*[@id="toggle"+0]' not found.]

Comment: try this one //*[@id="toggle"+${index}+""]

Comment: FAIL : Element with locator 'xpath= //*[@id="toggle"+0+""]' not found.

Comment: Don't try with '0' as you have to pass there index as variable. have your tried by replacing the same as i commented ?

Comment: Yes i ran the same code that you have shared. By initially as ${index} value is zero is in the first iteration. It is showing that error.

Comment: Is there any other elements with id that contains "toggle"? If no you could try something like `xpath=(//*[contains(@id, "toggle")])[index + 1]`

Comment: What does Form Locator do? Is that your custom keyword?

Comment: It's not working FAIL : Element with locator 'xpath=(//*[contains(@id, "toggle")])[0]' not found.

Comment: @LubosJerabek,   Yes it is a keyword that i was wrote to join "toggle${index}"

Comment: In xpath indexes start from 1

Comment: That's not how you concatenate strings in RF - you just put the variable in, and the framework substitutes it with its value on evaluation. E.g put this in your `Get Text` - `xpath=//*[@id="toggle${index}"]`; presuming `index` gets values from 0 to the last that's actually present, and there are actually element with those ids, that'll do.

Comment: @Todor xpath=//*[@id="toggle${index}"] worked. Thank you and to all the folks for giving different Inputs.